# Is every request to FB server from an App server hashed with the app secret

Tags: facebook, fbml

I have this question, before returning data to an app server, the fb server has to know if the request actually came from the genuine application server. For this purpose, is every api request hashed with the app secret?

Or how does the fb server verify the authenticity of the requesting server? I want to understanding the mechanism used by the oAuth protocol to accomplish this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request is not encrypted but the request is accompanied by a signed request parameter